# Center aligning the content of li inside a ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

Here is a vertical gallery.

```
http://www.braddockinfotech.com/demo/dvnonline/vod/
```

When a particular video in gallery is selected, the selection is left aligned.I hope the below picture makes it clear

[image]

How to make the selection center aligned.What i mean is at present the selection touches the left border of the container but not the right border of container(the orange dotted line).I want the selection to only select the inside video image and not the container border

Here is the html  code

```
    <body onkeydown="HandleKeyDown(event);">
    <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0px" class="sitewidth">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="width:800px;">
                <div id='divVideoPlayer'></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="width:140px;">
                <div id="divPlaylistContainer">
                    <div id="playlistNavPrev">
                        <a id="imgNavPrev" onclick="MoveToDirection('Up');"><span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divPlaylist">
                        <!--playlist-->
                        <div id="spanSlider" style='top:0px; position:relative;'>
                            <ul id="ulSlider">
                                <?php $index=1 ; $firstVideoUrl='' ; $firstImageUrl='' ; $videoDetails=G
                                etVideoDetails(); echo "<script> var siteUrl = '".$siteUrl.
                                "' </script>"; while ($row=m ysql_fetch_array($videoDetails)) { echo
                                "<script>video[".$index. "]='";echo $row[3]. "';</script>"; echo "<script>image[".$index.
                                "]='";echo $row[2]. "';</script>"; //echo "<script>title[".$index. "]='";echo
                                $row[1]. "';</script>"; echo "<script>title[".$index. "]='";echo str_replace(
                                "'", "\'",$row[1]). "';</script>"; // 0 - id , 1 - Title , 2- ImageUrl, 3
                                - VideoUrl //echo $row[0].$row[1].$row[2].$row[3]. "<br/>"; //echo
                                "<li id='liButton_".$index. "'><a  onclick=\"ShowVideo( '".$index."');\
                                "><img id='ImageButton_".$index. "' title='".$row[1]. "' alt='".$row[1]. "' src=".$siteUrl.
                                "timthumb/timthumb.php?src=".$row[2]. "&amp;h=54&amp;w=109&amp;zc=1&amp;a=c></a></li>"; $index++;
                                } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="playlistNavNxt">
                        <a id="imgNavNext" onclick="MoveToDirection('Down');"><span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
 var video = new Array();
 var image = new Array();
 var title = new Array();
 var noOfImagesCanShow = 6;
 var selected = 1;
 var slideNo = 1;


 String.prototype.trim = function () {
     return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
 };

 function SetPlayList() {
     var listHtml = '';
     var lastIndex = slideNo * noOfImagesCanShow;
     var firstIndex = (slideNo * noOfImagesCanShow) - (noOfImagesCanShow - 1);
     var rowNo = 1;
     for (var i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
         if (firstIndex >= 1 && lastIndex < title.length) {
             listHtml += "<li id='liButton_" + rowNo + "'><a  onclick=\"ShowVideo('" + i + "');\"><img id='ImageButton_" + i + "' title=\"" + title[i] + "\" alt='" + title[i] + "' src=" + siteUrl + "timthumb/timthumb.php?src=" + image[(i)] + "&amp;h=54&amp;w=109&amp;zc=1&amp;a=c></a></li>";
             rowNo++;
         }
     }
     document.getElementById('ulSlider').innerHTML = listHtml;
     document.getElementById('liButton_1').tabIndex = 2;
     document.getElementById('liButton_1').focus();
 }

 function ShowVideo(videoIndex) {
     var streamToBeUsed = "";
     var provideType = "";
     if (video[videoIndex].trim().substring(0, 7) == "http://") {
         streamToBeUsed = '';
         provideType = "http";
     } else {
         streamToBeUsed = "rtmp://cp87191.edgefcs.net/ondemand/";
         provideType = "rtmp";
     }
     var autostart = "true";

     if (jwplayer("divVideoPlayer") != null) {
         jwplayer("divVideoPlayer").stop();
     }

     jwplayer("divVideoPlayer").setup({
         file: streamToBeUsed + video[videoIndex].trim(),
         image: image[videoIndex],
         icons: "true",
         autostart: autostart,
         screencolor: "black",
         'width': '800',
         'height': '510',
         streamer: streamToBeUsed,
         provider: provideType,
         events: {
             onBeforePlay: function () {
                 document.getElementById('liButton_' + videoIndex).tabIndex = '2';
                 document.getElementById('liButton_' + videoIndex).focus();
             }
         }
     });
     // clearing all style
     var totalImages = noOfImagesCanShow;
     for (var i = 1; i <= totalImages; i++) {
         var imageId = (((slideNo * noOfImagesCanShow) - (noOfImagesCanShow)) + i).toString();
         if (document.getElementById('liButton_' + i) != null && document.getElementById('ImageButton_' + imageId) != null) {
             document.getElementById('liButton_' + i).className = 'inactiveli';
             document.getElementById('ImageButton_' + imageId).className = 'inactive';
         }
     }
     document.getElementById('liButton_' + videoIndex).className = 'activeli';
     document.getElementById('ImageButton_' + (((slideNo - 1) * noOfImagesCanShow) + parseInt(videoIndex)).toString()).className = 'active';

     SetButtonStatus(((slideNo - 1) * noOfImagesCanShow) + parseInt(videoIndex));


     document.getElementById('liButton_' + videoIndex).tabIndex = '2';
     document.getElementById('liButton_' + videoIndex).focus();
     document.getElementById('divVideoPlayer').tabIndex = '-1';

 }

 function SetButtonStatus(imageIndex) {
     if (imageIndex <= noOfImagesCanShow) {
         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').className = 'disable_up';
         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').tabIndex = '-1';
         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').tabIndex = '3';
     } else {
         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').className = 'enable_up';
         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').tabIndex = '1';
     }

     if (imageIndex > (image.length - noOfImagesCanShow)) {
         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').className = 'disable_down';
         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').tabIndex = '-1';
         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').tabIndex = '1';
     } else {
         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').className = 'enable_down';
         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').tabIndex = '3';
     }
 }

 function MoveToDirection(direction) {
     if (direction == 'Down') {
         if (document.getElementById('imgNavNext').className != 'disable_down') {
             slideNo++;
             SetButtonStatus(slideNo * noOfImagesCanShow);
             SetPlayList();
         }
     } else if (direction == 'Up') {
         if (document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').className != 'disable_up') {
             slideNo--;
             SetButtonStatus(slideNo * noOfImagesCanShow);
             SetPlayList();
             document.getElementById('liButton_6').focus();
         }
     }
 }

 function HandleKeyDown(ev) {
     if (document.activeElement != null) {
         var element = document.activeElement;

         if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
             /*User Pressed Enter, Handle If required*/
             if (element.id == "imgNavNext" && element.className != "disable_down") {
                 MoveToDirection('Down');
             } else if (element.id == "imgNavPrev" && element.className != "disable_up") {
                 MoveToDirection('Up');
             } else if (element.id.indexOf("liButton_") > -1) {
                 var nameSections = element.id.split('_');

                 ShowVideo(nameSections[1]);
             }
         } else if (ev.keyCode == 40) {
             /*User Pressed Down*/
             if (element.id.indexOf("liButton_") > -1) {
                 var nameSections = element.id.split('_');

                 var nextIndexToFocus = (parseInt(nameSections[1])) + 1;
                 if (document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus) != null) {
                     document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus).tabIndex = element.tabIndex;
                     element.tabIndex = "-1";
                     document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus).focus();
                 } else //need to focus in navNext
                 {
                     if (document.getElementById('imgNavNext').className != 'disable_down') {
                         document.getElementById('imgNavNext').focus();
                     }
                 }

             } else {
                 if (element.id.indexOf("imgNavPrev") > -1) {
                     document.getElementById("liButton_1").focus();
                 }
             }
         } else if (ev.keyCode == 38) {
             /*User Pressed Up Up*/
             if (element.id.indexOf("liButton_") > -1) {
                 var nameSections = element.id.split('_');

                 var nextIndexToFocus = (parseInt(nameSections[1])) - 1;
                 if (document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus) != null) {
                     document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus).tabIndex = element.tabIndex;
                     element.tabIndex = "-1";
                     document.getElementById("liButton_" + nextIndexToFocus).focus();
                 } else //need to focus in navPrev
                 {
                     if (document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').className != 'disable_up') {
                         document.getElementById('imgNavPrev').focus();
                     }
                 }
             } else /* To handle up button from imgNavNext */
             {
                 if (element.id.indexOf("imgNavNext") > -1) {
                     document.getElementById("liButton_6").focus();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Enter your HTML code or Make Jsfiddle

Comment: It kinda looks like you have a parent element around the image, which has padding-left that pushes the image to the center of the blue box and that padding would probably be the source of the problem. Without the actual code, we can only guess..

Comment: wait i'll post the code

Comment: Noticed the url at the top... took me a while... anyways.. I'm not sure how you want that selection to appear, but I think the simplest solution would be to show the selection around the `img`: `.activeli img { border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: i just want the selection to be around the image only

Comment: @Joonas i have updated my question with source code.Plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0 auto` to `.sitewidth`

```
.sitewidth {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i dont want the playing video to center align.I want the video selection in the gallery to center align.Have a look at the image attached in Question.I have marked it with red circle

Answer (score 0):

```
  .activeli 
   {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
   }
```

Comment: Your activeli div is nested inside `divPlaylistContainer` div u have to increase width of this div then the effect will apply

Comment: or reduce the width of activeli ? but selection partially overlaps the image.

Comment: well i cant increase the width of divPlaylistContainer.It wont look good.U can see for yourself by editing in browser developer console

Answer (score 0):

I think you had it aligned already. You can try it by just removing the padding given in  two of your **css- class**

```
#divPlaylistContainer {
    border: 1px solid #0080FF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
    margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
   /* padding: 0 10px 0 0;  padding removed */
    width: 140px;
}
```

moreover the padding from `#divPlaylist` can be removed.
source: http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

```
#divPlaylist ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    /*padding: 5px 0 5px 15px; padding removed*/
}
```

Or you can set `padding: 5px 15px;` for the **li**. I hope this will work for you.

Hmm... i have edited the answer. have a look
Add one more propertie in your css for `li` and `<a>` . Href has a dotted outline when you click it.

```
outline:0;
```

Possibly it will remove the dotted border around `li` and it will be cool :)

Comment: ok dat looks better but still the selection is over the li and not the video image, though its equally aligned from both sides.Is dere any way to make the selection over the video image only